# Maximizing image size on a powerpoint slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

[image]

I'm working on a slideshow with powerpoint 2007. I'm adding a series of jpeg images to consecutive slides. I'd like to maximize the size of each image so that it takes up the entire slide, but no more room. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the options in PPT's Insert | Photo Album feature.  One of the layouts may give you full slide images.

If you've already inserted the images and/or the Photo Album feature won't work, there's a "Hammer" tool in my free PPTools StarterSet add-in that lets you pick up the slide size, memorize it and then with one click, set any shape to fill that size (with or without distortion).

http://www.pptools.com/starterset/

This explains how to use it to set images to fill the slide:
http://www.pptools.com/starterset/FAQ00031.htm

Comment: thank you, I used the photo album feature to bulk import multiple jpegs.

Answer (score 0):

I never like the way Powerpoint scales and crops images (for full slide graphics) so I create mine in Photoshop to the correct slide size 13.333 x 7.5 at the correct resolution (usually 96 dpi). But I'm particular about cropping and placement.

If you're not concerned about that, you can create a box the size of the slide and fill it with the photo (this may stretch the image). OR scale the photo to fit the entire slide and use the crop tool.